# I'm having trouble ending a loop in C

Tags: c, loops

I'm in school learning C. (I am not asking for anyone to write this for me).

> **Assignment**
>   This program will calculate the miles per gallon **MPG** for you for three tanks of gas after you have entered the gallons used and miles driven.

I can get my program to start a loop, but I can't figure out how to make it end the loop after 3 runs and give me the Average MPG in 3 tanks. Running the program give me the average, but will keep asking forever.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int miles;
float gallons = -1, mg, overall = 0, avg = 0;
while(gallons != 0) {
  printf("Enter the gallons used: ");
  scanf("%f", &gallons);
  if (gallons == 0) {
    printf("\n\n The overall miles/gallon was: %f\n", overall/avg);
    exit(0);
    }
  printf("Enter miles driven: ");
  scanf("%d", &miles);
  mg = miles/gallons;
  printf("The miles/gallon for this tank was : %f\n", mg);
  overall += miles;
  avg += gallons;
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: int run = 3; while(run-- && gallons!=0) { ... }

Comment: "Running the program give me the average, but will keep asking forever" - do you mean that it prints "The overall ..." message but then continues with asking you about miles driven?

Comment: consider using more whitespace in your code. It's very taxing to read. [Example](https://ideone.com/TEPPi2).

Comment: It will keep asking the same 2 questions. Im trying to get it to stop after 3 loops and the average out the 3 MPG's. i hope that makes sense to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this small changes. Use an iterator to get average of 3 tanks.

Modify like

```
i=0;
while(i < 3) {
i++;
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int miles, **i=0;**  
float gallons = -1, mg, overall = 0, avg = 0; 
**while(i < 3)** {
  printf("Enter the gallons used: ");
  scanf("%f", &gallons);
  if (gallons == 0) {
    printf("\n\n The overall miles/gallon was: %f\n", overall/avg);
    exit(0);
    }
  printf("Enter miles driven: ");
  scanf("%d", &miles);
  mg = miles/gallons;
  printf("The miles/gallon for this tank was : %f\n", mg);
  overall += miles;
  avg += gallons;
  **i++;**
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this gives me a ton of errors. Do I need to remove the **

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry**: I did not see how is `gallons` being assigned/initialized in your code, I saw `float galons` and `while (gallons != 0)` and then thought that `gallons` was at some point the result of a computation.

This answer is still useful in my opinion.

Don't use `float` values to check conditions, `float`s are not accurate because their machine representation cannot be, so `gallons != 0` will probably hardly ever be true, use `int` instead and your loop control will work correctly. Only use `float` for the average value.

But in fact, because your specific problem can be solved with a `for` loop, you should use

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
```

instead, that way you know that it will only loop 3 times.

*SIDE NOTE*: learn more about `scanf()` and why you MUST check the value that it retuns in programs like yours.

Comment: Generally true, but I don't believe it's the case as zero is a number which can both be stored precisely and read precisely by scanf (e.g. if typed as `0`)

Answer (score 0):

Your program, as written, does not stop at 3 tanks. It will continuously ask for tanks until you answer 0 to the number of gallons used.

To make it read at most three tanks, replace `while (gallons != 0)` with `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`. That will make the main loop run three times only.

But then it won't print the overall average. It will simply quit after running three times. The code that shows the overall average is inside that `if` test that checks if you typed 0 gallons. Remove that `if` test and move the `printf` statement which shows the overall average near the end of the program, right before the `return` statement. This way it will run after the `for` loop runs 3 times.

Answer (score -2):

```
float gallons = -1;
```

It doesn't make any sense;
And you need to notice one thing that is

```
while(gallons!=0){
  //code
 }
```

You are asking the user to enter the value if gallons to input and your not changing it's value so this value will always be true in while and loop will go infinite.

If you need to run the loop three times then you can do it by using variable.
 `

```
int i=3;
while(i>0){//code 
i--;
}
```

Here I have edited your program ;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int miles,i=3;
float gallons, mg, overall = 0, avg = 0;
while(i>0) {
printf("Enter the gallons used: ");
scanf("%f", &gallons);
if (gallons == 0) {
   printf("\n\n The overall miles/gallon was: %f\n", overall/avg);
 exit(0);
   }
 printf("Enter miles driven: ");
 scanf("%d", &miles);
 mg = miles/gallons;
 printf("The miles/gallon for this tank was : %f\n", mg);
 overall += miles;
 avg += gallons;i--;
    }
 return 0;
 }
```

`

Comment: Declare a variable **int i=3 ;**and change 
 **while(gallons != 0 && i>0){//code 
i--;}**

Comment: ok, so I got that, however, it still continues in a loop. I cant get it to end and show the overall average MPG after 3 loops.

Comment: `float gallons=-1` initializes the variable to some value so that the while loop doesn't fail on the first run.  And yes, inside the `while` loop, he is indeed changing the value with the `scanf` call.

Comment: Whatever value you assign value to **gallons** it will change during the looping but as @Mike said he want to run the loop three times. By the way if you want to execute the loop first time then you also have **do-while**.

Comment: why down vote. I have run that my code successfully , you have any problem then give sample I/O.

Comment: It runs however, it does not show overall MPG after looping 3 times. Thats what I cant figure out. I cant have it look for me to enter 0 then give over all. it has to be automatic.